# XMLHttpRequest Post Data not being sent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, query-string

This is the javascript:

```
function eAC(emailData) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log(emailData);

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("email", emailData);

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = eAC_callback; 
    httpRequest.open('POST', "http://website.com/file.php");
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send(fd);
}

function eAC_callback() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                console.log(response);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

This is the php:

```
$pec_result = array();

if(isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){
    $pec_result['error'] = 'Its good';
    echo json_encode($pec_result);
    die();
} else {
    $pec_result['error'] = $_POST['email'];
    echo json_encode($pec_result);
    die();
}
```

The problem here is that `$_POST['email']` has a value of `NULL`. Why is $_POST['email'] null when console.log() for `emailData` returns a value. Can anyone help? I think the prob is in the appending part. (Not sure)

**Please no jQuery**. I know how to do this in jQuery but I want to learn how to do this in javascript. So yeah thanks

Comment: what is the browser you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that with `FormData` the request is sent as `multipart/form-data` not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Remove the line where you set the content type. The correct content type will be set automatically when you pass a `FormData` object to `XMLHttpRequest.send`.

Answer (score 3):

try this **(EDITED)**

```
fd='email='+emailData;
```

full code:

```
function eAC(emailData) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log(emailData);

//    var fd = new FormData();
//    fd.append("email", emailData);
      fd='email='+emailData;

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = eAC_callback; 
    httpRequest.open('POST', "http://website.com/file.php");
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send(fd);
}

function eAC_callback() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                console.log(response);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks its working now. But why did `new FormData()` not work in the code? Moz docs used it in their samples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: I don't know but lets think why jquery had write .serialize? It shows that we should send the data in query string format.

Comment: I had checked the link and the only thing I can guess is you should try it with FireFox too I think your solution and also mozilla's works in fire fox.

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: yup I got the answer. maybe it is a browser thing. its not specified in the page. Oh well. thanks again!

Comment: yourwelcome (-: . did you try mozilla way in firefox?

Comment: it actually failed there too. I tried it with the string fix you did and it worked same as chrome. So at least we know its not a browser thing. btw How do I append multiple variables? how do I separate them?

Comment: easy use `.serialize` in jquery or `var1=aaa&var2=fff` or write a function in javascript that gets a form and create the 'query string'