# How do I POST data from Dart to PHP asynchronously?

Tags: php, dart

I am trying to do some asynch behavior with Dart and PHP. Here's my code:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("name", "testing");
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest
  ..open('POST', path)
  ..setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => requestComplete(httpRequest))
  ..send(data);
```

`path` is set correctly. Since I'm doing asynch, I don't want to actually submit an entire form, which is why I have tried making my own FormData object and appending the information that I need to it. However, when I am in PHP, `$_POST['name']` is not set. I thought maybe it was the request header, but I tried changing that, and it didn't help. The only way I have gotten this to work (to set `$_POST['name']`) is to change `data` to `"name=testing"`. I have tried viewing the raw post data and it results in:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryUfDGArtA6R3ZWVoj Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name" testing------
WebKitFormBoundaryUfDGArtA6R3ZWVoj--
```

Submitting an actual form (without asynch) gives the correct behavior however. Is there another option aside from a key=value string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest Post Data not being sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181113/xmlhttprequest-post-data-not-being-sent)

Comment: I tried that answer yesterday among many others and nothing worked... Today, I take out the request header line again and now it's working... I wonder why it didn't work when I set the content-type to multipart/form-data. Oh well. Thanks for getting me to retry that.

Comment: The problem would be the boundary, if you set it in the content type header it would have to match the one generated by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is when you override the Content-Type header, you also overrode the boundary parameter to it. When posting multipart/form-data it needs additional info called a boundary, which lets it know on what to split the data. In this case the boundary needs to be:  ----WebKitFormBoundaryUfDGArtA6R3ZWVoj

I think this is take care of for you if you don't include the content type. The full content=type would be something like 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUfDGArtA6R3ZWVoj' when its all said and done, and must match the contents of your form data once build.

I think FormData takes care of that for you, or at least lets you pull it out and set it yourself.