# php image upload error in Chrome

Tags: php, image, google-chrome, upload

This script works for IE, but not for Chrome. (I curtailed the script for easy reading.)

It turns out that when using Chrome, `isset($_FILES['upfile']` returns false, so I get an error message, while using IE it returns true. Why?

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="upfile" onchange="SelectImage(this);">
```

JavaScript

```
function SelectImage(obj) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();
    req.open('POST', 'upload_image.php', true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
    data.append('upfile', obj.files[0]);
    req.send(data);
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
            console.log(req.responseText);
    };
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
try {
    if (!isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) || is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error']))
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
... much more (security) code ...
    echo 'something';
}
catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [XMLHttpRequest Post Data not being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181113/xmlhttprequest-post-data-not-being-sent).

I do not have to set the content type myself.
The correct type is automatically set when the `FormData` object is passed to `send()`

Thanks Musa!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your condition.
Your code:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) || is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error']))
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
```

checks that it hasn't any errors or error is an array and then throws an exception. 
Change it to

```
if (isset($_FILES['upfile']['error']) || is_array($_FILES['upfile']['error']))
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
```

Comment: This is not the cause.